# Multiselectlistpreference android retrieving values

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences, multi-select

im trying to retrieve the values but somehow i get alot more values back.
this is the code im running. Anyone knows what im doing wrong? i did search at alot of places but most is outdated. ( i checked item 2 and 3)
Just to make sure i only want to read out the selected checkboxes of the list but i have no idea where the 0-1-2-123 come from.

**pref_app.xml**

```
    <MultiSelectListPreference
        android:title="Categories"
        android:key="rssfeeds"
        android:summary="List to choose from"
        android:entries="@array/catos"
        android:entryValues="@array/catovalues"
        android:defaultValue="@array/catodefault"
        android:dialogTitle="Categories"
        >
    </MultiSelectListPreference>
```

**Strings.xml**

```
<string-array name="catos">
    <item >Movies</item>
    <item >Test</item>
    <item >TEst23</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="catovalues">
    <item >movies-checked</item>
    <item >test-checked</item>
    <item >test23-checked</item>
</string-array>
    <string-array name="catodefault">
    <item >movies-default</item>
    <item >test-default</item>
    <item >TEST23-default</item>
</string-array>
```

**return code in main xml**

```
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        Set<String> selections = preferences.getStringSet("rssfeeds", null);
        String[] selected= selections.toArray(new String[] {});
        for (int i = 0; i < selected.length ; i++){
            System.out.println("\ntest" + i +" : " + selected[i]);
        }
```

**Logcat result:**

```
01-15 14:15:49.016: I/System.out(4555): test0 : test23-checked
01-15 14:15:49.016: I/System.out(4555): test1 : 2
01-15 14:15:49.016: I/System.out(4555): test2 : 1
01-15 14:15:49.016: I/System.out(4555): test3 : 0
01-15 14:15:49.016: I/System.out(4555): test4 : 123
01-15 14:15:49.016: I/System.out(4555): test5 : test-checked
```

Comment: Search your code for where you put this info in the set. And btw you can simply `int i=0;for(Sting s: selections) {System.out.println("\ntest" + i++ +" : " + s);}` (and I would drop i)

Comment: @Veldmuus, are you sure code is working? I hit the following error: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Set`

Answer (score 2):

It stores only the ones that are checked.

You can put values ​​as indices.

```
<string-array name="catos">
    <item >Movies</item>
    <item >Test</item>
    <item >TEst23</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="catovalues">
    <item >0</item>
    <item >1</item>
    <item >2</item>
</string-array>

0 - Movies => Checked 
1 - Test   => Unchecked 
2 - TEst23 => Checked
```

In the preferences file will only indexes 0 and 2, and you can assume that others are unmarked.

So if you analyze the `Set <String>`,  its size will be only 2 `strings` with 0 and 2.

Comment: Thanks, @cicero-moura. And how to find which exact item is checked?

Answer (score -1):

Have a try the below codes:

```
for(String s: selections){
    if("movies-checked".equals(s)) {
    }
    if("test-checked".equals(s)) {
    }
    if("test23-checked".equals(s)) {
    }
}
```