# Disable multiple checkbox items in Android Settings activity by identifying checkboxes with specific string prefix in in their label

Tags: android, material-design, application-settings

I am using the Settings activity, that is automatically generated when using Context Action menu (New -> Activity -> Settings Activity). Activity with corresponding classes and files was initially generated in AS 4.0 ; now using Android Studio 4.2 Beta 4.

As I have various app flavors, I need to dynamically/programmatically *remove or disable part of available checkbox and radio button items*, based on the gradle build flavor and the entryValue prefix. Let's say it is '[XYZ]' string, which marks those entries, which should be unusable by app user.

Here is snipp from my Settings activity for radio and checkbox entries:

```
    <MultiSelectListPreference
        app:dependency="autoconfig"
        app:dialogTitle="Choose configuration taking effect"
        app:key="autoconfig_behavior"
        app:entries="@array/autoconfig_entries"
        app:entryValues="@array/autoconfig_values"
        app:defaultValue="@array/empty_array"
        app:title="Click to select items"
        app:summary="Choose your preferred Advanced configuration items..." />

    <ListPreference
        app:defaultValue="google"
        app:entries="@array/reply_entries"
        app:entryValues="@array/reply_values"
        app:key="reply"
        app:title="@string/reply_title"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />
```

Based on this, I am trying to figure out, how to disable or remove or hide or whatever all the items within the List* and MultiSelectList* entries, that has certain string prefix in their entryValues.

I have read mmaannyy SO questions and no sample really works. The official documentation for me is more confusing than helpful. Therefore - how to do it?

Comment: Noone? Seriously? :(

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139373/multiselectlistpreference-android-retrieving-values